# scroll partial rect using ScrollWindowEx winapi

Tags: c++, winapi, codeblocks

I am trying to get partial scrolling to work. The code below makes it look like (visually) the window is partially scrolling but the buttons do not actually move. After scrolling if we click the buttons, or overlap another window over, it will bring the buttons back to its original position without moving the scrollbar.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <commctrl.h>

long scrollY = 0;
RECT rect;
HINSTANCE hinst;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT Message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch(Message) {

        case WM_CREATE: {

            CreateWindowEx(WS_OVERLAPPED,"Button","Button 1", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_PUSHBUTTON, 5, 5, 200, 50, hwnd,(HMENU) 10001,hinst,NULL);
            CreateWindowEx(WS_OVERLAPPED,"Button","Button 2", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_PUSHBUTTON, 5, 55, 200, 50, hwnd,(HMENU) 10002,hinst,NULL);
            CreateWindowEx(WS_OVERLAPPED,"Button","Button 3", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_PUSHBUTTON, 5, 105, 200, 50, hwnd,(HMENU) 10003,hinst,NULL);
            CreateWindowEx(WS_OVERLAPPED,"Button","Button 4", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_PUSHBUTTON, 5, 155, 200, 50, hwnd,(HMENU) 10004,hinst,NULL);
            CreateWindowEx(WS_OVERLAPPED,"Button","Button 5", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_PUSHBUTTON, 5, 205, 200, 50, hwnd,(HMENU) 10005,hinst,NULL);

            SCROLLINFO si;
            si.cbSize = sizeof(SCROLLBARINFO);
            si.fMask = SIF_ALL;
            si.nMax = 40;
            si.nMin = 0;
            si.nPage = 10;
            si.nPos = 0;
            si.nTrackPos = 0;
            SetScrollInfo(hwnd,SB_VERT,&si,TRUE);
            GetClientRect(hwnd, &rect);
            break;
        }

        case WM_VSCROLL:{
            RECT rc;
            int CurPos = scrollY;
            int TemPos = CurPos;
                switch (LOWORD(wParam))
                {
                case SB_TOP:            CurPos = 0; break;
                case SB_LINEUP:         CurPos = (CurPos > 0)? CurPos - 1 : 0; break;
                case SB_THUMBPOSITION:  CurPos = HIWORD(wParam); break;
                case SB_THUMBTRACK:     CurPos = HIWORD(wParam); break;
                case SB_LINEDOWN:       CurPos = (CurPos < 240)? CurPos + 1 : 240; break;
                case SB_BOTTOM:         CurPos = 240; break;
                case SB_ENDSCROLL:      break;
                }

            SetScrollPos(hwnd, SB_VERT, CurPos, TRUE);
            TemPos = CurPos - TemPos;
            rc = rect;
            rc.top = rc.top + 55;
            ScrollWindowEx(hwnd, 0, -TemPos, &rc, &rc, NULL, NULL, SW_ERASE | SW_INVALIDATE);
            scrollY = CurPos;
            break;
        }

        case WM_DESTROY: {
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        }

    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, Message, wParam, lParam);
}

/*Standard WinMain omitted for brevity*/
```

Edit:
I want the leave Button1 visible while scrolling. Partially scroll the window.

Comment: @Barmak did you delete your reply? Is what I am asking not possible or is it too complex to be posted here. please give me some direction or a clue.

Comment: I don't know how to partially scroll the window, or if that's possible at all.

Comment: @HansPassant This does scroll child windows with `SW_SCROLLCHILDREN` flag, or just using `ScrollWindow`. Or you mean the invalidate/area parameters are just for pixels?

Comment: @HansPassant it works fine if I leave rect as NULL which moves the entire client area. The buttons also respond as expected. Another interesting test, when I use ScrollWindow(hwnd, 0, -TemPos, NULL, &rc) (old scroll function) the buttons respond fine as excepted but Button1 gets wiped off when the window is repainted.

Answer (score 0):

As it's said in the documentation, ScrollWindowEx function scrolls client area of given window. It does not move other windows. To scroll the buttons, you may store them in an array of HWNDs, and then move them using for example MoveWindow function.